# Prove that a function defines homotopy equivalence

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

$X,Y$ topological spaces. Let maps $f:X\to Y$ , $g,g':Y\to X$ s.t. $fg$ is homotopic to $Id_Y$ and $g'f$ is homotopic to $Id_X$.
Prove that $f$ defines homotopy equivalence.

I would be happy for any help, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $f$ and $h=g'fg$, $fh=f(g'f)g$ is homotopic to $fg$ since $g'f$ is homotopic to the identity, we deduce that $fh$ is homotopic to the identity.

On the other hand, 
$hf=g'(fg)f$ is homotopic to $g'f$.